# Book recommendation for advanced calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I have studied some basic advanced calculus courses, which I have learnt how to compute gradient, divergence, surface integral volume integral. However, the course doesn't provide much rigorous proof of those divergence theorem or other theorems. So I want to study these kind of things rigorously and also learn more about these things in higher dimension.

Is there any books which is good for self study?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, since computing integrals and such is not something that is really studied. However, it seems that you are interested in vector calculus, so you should probably look up differential geometry and smooth manifolds.

Comment: @ErikJoensson Yes I'm interested in vector calculus, is there any book about differential geometry and smooth manifolds which is for self-study?

Comment: I know very little of those topics, so I can only refer you to an answer below.

Comment: I am curious after 6 years which book did you learn from ?

Answer (score 1):

You can read " An Introduction to Manifolds " by Loring.W.Tu . But, I personally recommend " An Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds and Riemannian Geometry " by William. M. Boothby .